# How to convert 'UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.originalImage' into 'UIImage'

Tags: swift, uiimage, uiimagepickercontroller

I'm developping an iOS phone app and I want to take a picture and store it in the app.

I am able to take the picture using a UIImagePickerController but I can't store it in my database. I'm using CoreData to store data in this app but for the picture, it seems that it is easier to store the picture in a folder and store the file path in Coredata. The issue is that I can get the picture i've took with the camera but I can't get the PNG data to store it in my folder.

```
func takePhoto(){
        //Take the picture with the camera
        imagePickerController = UIImagePickerController()
        imagePickerController.delegate = self
        if !UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(.camera){
            let alertController = UIAlertController.init(title: nil, message: "Camera is not available", preferredStyle: .alert)
            let okAction = UIAlertAction.init(title: "Alright", style: .default, handler: {(alert: UIAlertAction!) in })
            alertController.addAction(okAction)
            self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
        else{ imagePickerController.sourceType = .camera }

        present(imagePickerController, animated: true, completion: nil)

        //Store the picture in an app folder
        let fileManager = FileManager.default
        let imagePath = (NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)[0] as NSString).appendingPathComponent("image")
        let picture = UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.originalImage as? UIImage
        let data = picture?.pngData()
        fileManager.createFile(atPath: imagePath as String, contents: data, attributes: nil)

        //Store the file path in CoreData
        let image = Image(context: self.persistenceManager.context)
        image.pathName = imagePath
        self.persistenceManager.saveContext()
}
```

The problem is when I try to get the png data. I need a UIImage to use `.pngData()` but when I try to convert my picture object into UIImage from `UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.originalKey` I have the following warning message:

> "Cast from 'UIImagePickerController.InfoKey' to unrelated type 'UIImage' always fails". 
>   Also, I don't understand why I need to convert it because I found in the AppleDevelopper website that: "The value for this key is a UIImage object." (the key is "static let originalImage: UIImagePickerController.InfoKey" )

I've also tried to let my picture object as an `UIImagePickerController.InfoKey` object without converting it into an UIImage object but in this case I have the following error message:

> "Value of type `'UIImagePickerController.InfoKey'` has no member 'pngData' "
>    and the method UIImagePNGRepresentation() is not working because the expected argument type is also 'UIImage'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.originalImage` is a String... it's a key, not the actual image.

You should use the [UIImagePickerControllerDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiimagepickercontrollerdelegate), like so

```
extension ViewController: UIImagePickerControllerDelegate {

    func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, 
      didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {

        let image = info[.originalImage] as? UIImage
    }

}
```

You see, the information from the UIPickerController is passed as a dictionary with the type `[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]`, `UIImagePicker.InfoKey` contains all of the Keys that are used in this dictionary, so you use these to access the values.

EDIT:

So your takePhoto function only needs to display the picker, then handle the response later in the delegate method:

```
func takePhoto(){
    //Take the picture with the camera
    imagePickerController = UIImagePickerController()
    imagePickerController.delegate = self
    if !UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(.camera){
        let alertController = UIAlertController.init(title: nil, message: "Camera is not available", preferredStyle: .alert)
        let okAction = UIAlertAction.init(title: "Alright", style: .default, handler: {(alert: UIAlertAction!) in })
        alertController.addAction(okAction)
        self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    else{ imagePickerController.sourceType = .camera }

    present(imagePickerController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Then in your delegate you can work with the selected image

```
extension ViewController: UIImagePickerControllerDelegate {

    func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, 
      didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {

       let fileManager = FileManager.default
       let imagePath = (NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)[0] as NSString).appendingPathComponent("image")
       let picture = info[.originalImage] as? UIImage
       let data = picture?.pngData()
       fileManager.createFile(atPath: imagePath as String, contents: data, attributes: nil)

       //Store the file path in CoreData
       let image = Image(context: self.persistenceManager.context)
       image.pathName = imagePath
       self.persistenceManager.saveContext()
    }

}
```

Comment: But I don't understand how to access the variable image in my function after that.

Comment: I have updated my answer. You can't do it all in one function. The user needs to actually take the photo, this all takes time. The delegate is called when the user has finished selecting their photo so that is the place to work with the image

Answer (score 1):

As @Scriptabel has stated,

you'll need to use this delegate and access/save your image inside the function.

```
Class VC: UIViewController, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate { 

func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {


let picture = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.originalImage] as! UIImage
let data = picture.pngData()        

    //Store the picture in an app folder
    let fileManager = FileManager.default
    let imagePath = (NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)[0] as NSString).appendingPathComponent("image")


    fileManager.createFile(atPath: imagePath as String, contents: data, attributes: nil)

    //Store the file path in CoreData
    let image = Image(context: self.persistenceManager.context)
    image.pathName = imagePath
    self.persistenceManager.saveContext()

 }
}
```